# How to specify the chunksize of large array saved in -v7.3 matfile?

Tags: matlab, hdf5, mat-file

I'm saving large data array to mat file.

```
m = matfile('data.mat','writable',true);
m.X(1000,1000,10,50000) = nan(1,'single');
for ii = 1 : 50000
  % do some computation
  m.X(1:1000,1:1000,1:10,ii) = Y;
end
```

How can I set ChunkSize of `X` to [1000,1000,1,1]?

Comment: Don't think you can influence it. What is your goal behind changing the chunksize?

Comment: @Daniel because the matfile will be huge and in the postprocessing, I need to read them frame by frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `matfile` command, but you use the HDF5 api. Since [matfiles v7.3 use the HDF5 format](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/mat-file-versions.html), i guess it should also work on the reading side for you? Here is a small example from the documentation:

```
h5create('myfile.h5','/DS3',[20 Inf],'ChunkSize',[5 5]);
for j = 1:10
      data = j*ones(20,1);
      start = [1 j];
      count = [20 1];
      h5write('myfile.h5','/DS3',data,start,count);
end
h5disp('myfile.h5');
```

[Source of the example](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/h5write.html)